# Any way to edit values in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I've parsed through a file to extract certain values. A column contains a percentage with the symbol. Is there any way to remove that "%" character?

From this:

```
98.9%   23    43
92.2%   342   34
98.9%   53    53
82.2%   32    76
97.9%   83    45
92.9%   92    23
```

to:

```
98.9   23    43
92.2   342   34
98.9   53    53
82.2   32    76
97.9   83    45
92.9   92    23
```

Answer (score 7):

You say in the title that you have a matrix - in which case everything in the matrix should be 'character' already.  Use `gsub` to replace % with nothing.

```
> j <- matrix(c("1%", "2%", 3, 4), ncol = 2)
> j
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1%" "3" 
[2,] "2%" "4" 
> gsub("%", "", j)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "4"
```

if you want it to be numeric you could use `apply` along with `as.numeric`

```
> apply(gsub("%", "", j), 1, as.numeric)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

Comment: Seems like it's inherent in gsub.

Answer (score 2):

Use `gsub` to substitute the `%` for an empty string, then convert to numeric:

```
x <- c("98.9%", "92.2%", "98.9%", "82.2%", "97.9%", "92.9%")
as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x))
[1] 98.9 92.2 98.9 82.2 97.9 92.9
```