# Mean of triplicate

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I've just cleaned up a data frame that I scraped from an excel spreadsheet by amongst other things, removing percentage signs from some of the numbers see, [Removing Percentages from a Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385060/removing-percentages-from-a-data-frame).

The data has twenty four rows representing the parameters and results from eight experiments done in triplicate.  Eg, what one would get from,

```
DF1 <- data.frame(X = 1:24, Y = 2 * (1:24), Z = 3 * (1:24))
```

I want to find the mean of each of the triplicates (which, fortunately are in sequential order) and create a new data frame with eight rows and the same amount of columns.

I tried to do this using,

```
DF2 <- data.frame(replicate(3,sapply(DF1, mean)))
```

which gave me the mean of each column as rows three times.  I wanted to get a dataframe that would give me,

```
data.frame(X = c(2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23), Y = c(4,10,16,22,28,34,40,23), Z = c(6,15,24,33,42,51,60,69))
```

which I worked out by hand; it's supposed to be the reduced result.

Thanks, ...

Any help would be gratefully recieved.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945703/r-calculate-row-means-on-specific-columns

Comment: thanks for the link @Rachel, it is close to but not quite what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
foo <- matrix(unlist(by(data=DF1,INDICES=rep(1:8,each=3),FUN=colMeans)),
  nrow=8,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(foo) <- colnames(DF1)
```

Look at `?by`.

Comment: Hi @Stephan, your code almost works.  I've lost my column headings.  I tried the script again using 'data.frame' instead of 'matrix' but this returned a mess.  I'll stick to your script and use 'names' to put the headers back if nothing else turns up.  Thanks,

Comment: I edited the code to add the `colnames`. But @Tomas' solution is much prettier, anyway, so +1 to him.

Answer (score 4):

Nice task for codegolf!

```
aggregate(DF1, list(rep(1:8, each=3)), mean)[,-1]
```

to be more general, you should replace `8` with `nrow(DF1)`.

... or, my favorite, using matrix multiplication:

```
t(t(DF1) %*% diag(8)[rep(1:8,each=3),]/3)
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers.  Does the first one return a data.frame and the second one return a matrix?  I ask because the way that R returns the results looks slightly different.

Comment: @user1945827, exactly. You can typecast them using `as.matrix` or `as.data.frame`.

Comment: in the first answer, when I change '8' with nrow(DF1) I get an error returned.  Don't know why, thought you might like to know, though.

Comment: @user1945827 - works for me. What error you get? Is the DF1 still the original `data.frame` as you defined it in your question?

Comment: " Is the DF1 still the original...".  Ah, no.  The other pieces of code provided by yourself and others is more than sufficient.  I'll regenerate the error and post back here tomorrow.