# Currency conversion in R

Tags: r, currency

I am trying to convert currency values from factor to numeric. The format is €110.5M €565K I was able to get rid of € sign, M and K letters but I also need to make the conversion as to show `110.5M=110.500.000` and `565K=565.000`. Is there a way that you can suggest?

```
value<-as.numeric(gsub("[€MK]", "", as.character(strength[1:18207,1])))
```

Data to be converted

```
€110.5M €565K
€77M    €405K
€118.5M €290K
```

Comment: There's a pretty similar post already here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15014333/5325862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
out <- unname(sapply(gsubfn("M|K", list(M = "* 1e6", K = "* 1e3"), 
    sub("€", "", str1)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
out
#[1] 110500000    565000  77000000    405000 118500000    290000

scales::dollar_format(prefix = "", big.mark = ".")(out)
#[1] "110.500.000" "565.000"     "77.000.000"  "405.000"   
#[4] "118.500.000" "290.000"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("€110.5M",  "€565K", "€77M", "€405K", "€118.5M", "€290K")
```

Comment: Thank you. Just tried and got [1] 110.5 as result. It needs to be 110.500.000 for M and 110.500 for K

Comment: @Jean I get `[1] 110500000    565000  77000000    405000 118500000    290000`

Comment: @Jean I formatted with `dollar_format`.  Can you check the output now

Comment: Well it worked for € format for one single value, but the problem now is when I enter a column of 18000 rows, it shows an errorBrowse[1]> sapply(exp, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
Error during wrapup: <text>:1:1: unexpected input
1: €
    ^

Comment: @Jean It should work whether it is a single value or multple value if the format of the strings is as showed in the example.  Do you have a `factor` or `character` column

Comment: @Jean My doubt is whether you have strings `"€110.5M"` or `"€110.5M €565K"`

Comment: I am getting an error at parse function. I think it does not recognise some values in the column. By the way I am working with Fifa2019 Dataset from Kaggle, Value column

Comment: @Jean If you can dput a small reprodcuible example that gives the error then it would be easier to debug

Comment: I think have problems with 0 € values.

Comment: One second akrun

Comment: @Jean Please make sure that the `dput` includes an example that gives the error

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IgpH5p3.png you can see the error and the print out for the first line of the code. There is something wrong with 0 € values. They include € and a space before 0. Can this be the problem? Because it does not fit the format of others and text parser gives an error.

Comment: @Jean Can you check entry no. 997.  What is the actual value

Comment: @Jean Just a doubt, are you executing my function or from the other post

Comment: :) Yes akrun I was running the code from other post. This code is ok and works for one value and also 18000 value. No problems for now. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar base R option using `sub`:

```
input <- c("€110.5M", "€565K")
exp <- sapply(input, function(x) sub("€(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)K", "\\1*1000",
                  sub("€(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)M", "\\1*1000000", x)))
exp
sapply(exp, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))

€110.5M           €565K 
"110.5*1000000"      "565*1000" 
  €110.5M     €565K 
110500000    565000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Tim. The code works for one value but gives an error with my entire dataset. https://pasteboard.co/IgpH5p3.png There may be a problem with 0 values. My problem is ok but I wanted to reply you.